# Uber payment with Campus One Card

Tags: payment, uber-api

We would like to integrate campus card payments to the Uber App. This has already been done by another provider with a school but I don't see anything in the API docs referencing this so I assume this is custom with Uber.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this question does not reference anything in Uber's [publicly available API.](https://developer.uber.com/docs) If you are looking for a custom partnership with Uber, here is Uber's [partnership request form.](https://help.uber.com/h/b819b839-8591-447b-9091-efcc4ade7b41)  Hope that helps!